# Frame for buttons

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I use this code so that when you click on a button its background changes to a picture with a white border and when you press it again it changes to a picture with a gray background (the button always has a gray background).

You can make it so that when you click on another button, the background changes in the other buttons (If I clicked on "+" and the frame appeared when I clicked on the "-" button, then the "+" frame would disappear)

[image: **On/ff button**]

[**CODE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iFaQ.png):

```
@IBAction func PercentAnimate(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.currentBackgroundImage == image_off {    
        sender.setBackgroundImage(Image_on, for: .normal)         
    } else {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(image_off, for: .normal)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to keep a reference to a previously clicked button.

```
@IBAction func PercentAnimate(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.currentBackgroundImage == image_off {    
        sender.setBackgroundImage(Image_on, for: .normal)         
    } else {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(image_off, for: .normal)
    } 
    if (previousButton !== sender) {
        previousButton.setBackgroundImage(image_off, for: .normal)
        previousButton = sender
    }
}
```

Comment: Error with previousButton

Comment: you will need to declare it.

Comment: you can declare it globally. like let previousButton = UIButton()

Comment: happened to declare but now he does not like "!"

Comment: Writes this - Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type "UIiButton"

Comment: I don't know how you  are writing it. If you just paste the code that I have provided. Seems like you are writing it like previousButton! == sender instead of previousButton !== sender